# Table loaded from database won't send correct data via POST

Tags: php, mysql

I am loading a table from a mysql database. I have included in a form since I want users to be able to make changes to the database and submit. The data loads from the db fine, but when I change a value and hit submit, it always sends the data of the last row of the table, and not the value I changed. How can I send the whole table to the db? The `$stid` is correct.

```
<?php 
$q3 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM stores_op_hours WHERE Store_Id='$stid'
order by field(Day_Name,'sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat')" );

?>
<form action="store-admin.php" method="post">
<table class="table ophours">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">       
        <tr><th>Day</th><th>Open Time</th><th>Close Time</th><th>Notes</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 

while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($q3)){

    $day = $rw['Day_Name'];
    $op = $rw['Open_Time'];
    $cl = $rw['Close_Time'];
    $day2 = strtoupper($day);
    $notes = $rw['Store_Op_Notes'];
?>  
        <input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?php echo $day; ?>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="stid" value="<?php echo $stid; ?>" >
        <tr><td><input type="text" readonly name="day2" value="<?php echo $day2; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open" value="<?php echo $op; ?>" > </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close" value="<?php echo $cl; ?>" > </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="notes"<?php echo $notes; ?> ></td></tr>

<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="ophourchange" name="ophourchange" value="Save Changes" >
</form>
```

The POST code:

```
if(isset($_POST['ophourchange'])){
    $stid = $_POST['stid'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $open = $_POST['open'];
    $close = $_POST['close'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('stid". $stid."')</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('day". $day."')</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('open". $open."')</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('close". $close."')</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('notes". $notes."')</script>";

    $upd_st_op = " UPDATE stores_op_hours SET Open_Time='$open', Close_Time='$close', Store_Op_Notes='$notes' WHERE Store_Id='$stid' AND Day_Name='$day' ";

    $res = mysqli_query($link, $upd_st_op);
    if (!mysqli_query($link,$res))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error". mysqli_error($link)."')</script>";
    }else{
        //echo "Store Updated";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Store Open Hours Updated')</script>";

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to make the names of your input fields arrays like `day[0]` then loop through the array(s) when posted.

Comment: Or, each row can be its own form

Comment: Or you can use JavaScript to capture the data (that's a little more complex )

Comment: @Rasclatt, if I make each row be its own form, won't the submit button iterate too? That doesn't look very nice

Comment: You can make it look however you want, if you just want one button to submit, then you need to array the inputs as I mentioned and as @tamil below is demonstrating.

Comment: @Rasclatt, okay I got it working, but I had to add another column to the table, to accomodate the submit button.Is there a way to display only one button?

Comment: To have just one button, you have to submit the whole table but that is why then you would need to array the input names.

Comment: but as I mentioned in a comment to his answer, I have only one set of values, and it is iterated by the while loop. how do I give the values data[0], data[1]? Can you please show me in code? @Rasclatt

Comment: There are a couple ways. Best would be to use the id *(presumably you have auto increment of the table you are selecting from)* or before the `while(` you do `$i=0; while(` then before the end brace, increment the `$i` like `$i++ }` If you still want a sample I can show you.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code you need the auto-incrementing id for each row that you are echoing in order to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your rows use your row `id`, assuming you have an auto-incrementing `id` column in your table:

```
while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($q3)){
    // You need to have this column here
    $id    =  $rw['id'];
    $day   =  $rw['Day_Name'];
    $op    =  $rw['Open_Time'];
    $cl    =  $rw['Close_Time'];
    $day2  =  strtoupper($day);
    $notes =  $rw['Store_Op_Notes'];
?>  
        <input type="hidden" name="day[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $day; ?>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="stid[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $stid; ?>" >
        <tr><td><input type="text" readonly name="day2[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $day2; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="open[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $op; ?>" > </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="close[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $cl; ?>" > </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="notes[<?php echo $id; ?>]"<?php echo $notes; ?> ></td></tr>
<?php
}
```

Then your sql statement *(which you are just testing now but will fix all the injection issues later, no doubt)* would have the `id` as another parameter to match:

```
"UPDATE `stores_op_hours`
    SET `Open_Time` = '$open',
        `Close_Time` = '$close',
        `Store_Op_Notes` = '$notes'
    WHERE
        `id` = '{$id}'";
```

Comment: ah yes!, and how do I get the value via POST? `$_POST['data'];`?

Comment: No, you will have a series of post arrays.

Comment: Try doing what I have, then `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get. Then you can actually tailor your input names to how you want to receive the array(s).

Comment: how do I get the values from it? sorry I'm confused

Comment: Do what I have, then submit the form. On the page, just `print_r($_POST)` and that will show you all the arrays created. From there, you can see how to organize the data.

Comment: So you may want to do `name="data[<?php echo $id; ?>][day]"`, you can organize the inputs how you want, try submitting, you will see what the arrays look like.

Comment: I took away the unnecessary values and now I get the result array like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/knby35ey/ how do I add these values to the variables?

Comment: So judging by that array, you would use `foreach($array as $id => $rows)` then do the update sql inside this loop.

Comment: Wait, did you paste the array twice or do you have two identical arrays?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111187/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-rasclatt).

Answer (score 0):

give each input a name like

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[0][day]" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[0][stid]" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="data[1][day]" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[1][stid]" value="" />
```

then in php

```
$_POST['data'];
```

will be an array

Comment: I have these defined only once. the while loop iterates saving the data to the table

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your while loop like following :-

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($q3)){

    $day = $rw['Day_Name'];
    $op = $rw['Open_Time'];
    $cl = $rw['Close_Time'];
    $day2 = strtoupper($day);
    $notes = $rw['Store_Op_Notes'];
?>  
    <input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['day']" value="<?php echo $day; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['stid']" value="<?php echo $stid; ?>" >
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" readonly name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['day2']" value="<?php echo $day2; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['open']" value="<?php echo $op; ?>" > </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['close']" value="<?php echo $cl; ?>" > </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['notes']" value="<?php echo $notes; ?>" ></td>   
    </tr>

<?php
 $i++;
}
?>
```

Then You can test data with $_POST['data'];

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($_POST['data']);
?>
```

It may help you

Comment: when I echo $_POST['data'], I get the result as "Array"

Comment: Sorry please use print_r($_POST['data']);

Comment: You can check it in my answer.